# Determining whether a user is logged in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

when i try to test to redict to api/todo it's not working my condition any idea ?when i try to test to redict to api/todo it's not working my condition any idea

**app.js**

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location,$log,User) {

     $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event,next, current) {



         if (!User.signin() && next.authenticate === true){
                // User isn’t authenticated
                $location.path('/signin');
            }
 });
```

**service.js**

```
  signin: function(data){

                    return $sails.post('/api/auth',data);
                },
```

**Controller**

```
 .controller('SigninCtrl', function ($scope,$location,User,$http) {             


    $scope.signin = function(){
    var data={ email:$scope.email,password:$scope.password}
       var user=User.signin(data);
        //console.log(typeof user);
     user.success(function (data) {
                    //console.log("token signin",data);
                    var token=data.token;
                localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
                    $location.path("/todo");
               })
               .error(function (data) {
                    //Do whatever is needed
                 //console.log(data);
               });  
        }   

  });
```

Comment: "Redict" isn't a word I'm familiar with in this context. What do you mean by it? Also, please use punctuation to properly form complete sentences. It's hard to understand your question.

Comment: @isherwood i want to check if user is logged or not

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify. "... test to redict to" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: What you have copied here for 'controller' part is signup stuff. I can't see any thing about signin. In app.js you are calling 'User.signin'. Typo or something?

Comment: @NimaMarashi i edite controller check please